# Create skew div side by side

Tags: html, css-transforms, skew

How do i create like the image using two div?

[image]

I have search many used skew and I tried but didn't get exactly like the image.
only skew the div. not the content inside.

Here is what I have tried:

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
   width: 50%;
   -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
.right{
    float: left;
   background-color: #666;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj4bLugd/) here what i have done

Comment: skew without effecting content inside div

Comment: Please post the code in your question, so that is is searchable for people wondering the same thing.

Comment: There you go. Now the question looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this. I used a gradient background and CSS grid to create two divs inside that are not skewed. A couple of caveats:

- You will need to use padding on both sides to keep your text from running over the top of your color change.
- You may need to use webkit for browser support of the linear gradient, depending on which older browser you intend to support.

```css
.container {
 background: linear-gradient(45deg,#FF0000 50%,#666666 50%);
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto;
 width: 100%;
}
.side {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="side">
   test
 </div>
 <div class="side">
   test
 </div>
</div>
```